# Como manipular um array no formato json em asp classic

Tags: json, array, asp

Bom minha situação é o seguinte, eu tenho uma variável que me traz os seguintes resultados:

```
 var1 = [{"id_item":2,"posicao":1},{"id_item":8,"posicao":2},{"id_item":9,"posicao":3},{"id_item":7,"posicao":4},{"id_item":10,"posicao":5}]
```

eu preciso manipular esse resultado separadamente, por exemplo

```
r1 = id_item
r2 = posicao
```

como eu conseguiria pegar os resultados deste array separadamente no asp classic,

tentei fazer um:

```
teste =  JSON.parse(var1)
```

para tentar pegar o resultado dessa forma `teste.id_item` mais quando dou um response.write não aparece nada.
e quado executo um response.write na variavel teste resultado que eu  é sempre esse.

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

qual seria a solução mais correta para esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Asp utilizo o componente AspJson
http://www.aspjson.com/

Veja a Leitura:

```
<!--#include virtual="/aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON

'Carregar a String
oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)

'Get valor simples
Response.Write oJSON.data("firstName") & "<br>"

'Percorrer a coleção
For Each phonenr In oJSON.data("phoneNumber")
    Set this = oJSON.data("phoneNumber").item(phonenr)
    Response.Write _
    this.item("type") & ": " & _
    this.item("number") & "<br>"
Next

'Atualizar/Adicionar valores
oJSON.data("firstName") = "James"

'Retornar String Json
Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
%>
```